# Prevent caching data of a dataTable

Tags: html, jsf, icefaces-3

I have a `ice:dataTable` and in each row, there is a `inputText`. The record list is updated every time when fire a `valueChangeListener` on some other component.
When it resets the record list, browser shows the previous values for `inputText` fields in table rows.

I tried both `Filter` and `<meta/>` tags. It didn't work for me.
Can somebody tell me how to get rid of this problem?
(Backing bean keeps the actual record list)

Answer (score 1):

This is a JSF problem, take a look at the following answer for details

[Input fields hold previous values only if validation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371723/input-fields-hold-previous-values-only-if-validation-failed)

To make it simple JSF keeps values in the partialViewContext so all what you have to do to reset all components in the partialViewContext

or if you are using primefaces you can simply add  < p:resetInput target="tableId"/> to the field (nested inside) or if you are using  OmiFaces then you can use ResetInputAjaxActionListener