# jsf 2.0 issue 1060 : what about jsf 2.1 and 2.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

Well, i think everyone had encountered this problem in `jsf 2.0`:
[Input fields hold previous values only if validation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371723/input-fields-hold-previous-values-only-if-validation-failed)

I'm asking : did this problem persist with `jsf 2.1` and `jsf 2.2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JSF 2.2 it was introduced a new tag called f:resetValues. See this blog [JSF 2.2: Reset input fields on JSF Live](http://jsflive.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/jsf-22-reset-values) for details.